# What does lea 0x4(%esp),%ecx mean in AT&T syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

What does `lea 0x4(%esp),%ecx` mean in at&t assembly?

What really is `0x4(%esp)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `%esp + 0x4`.

`LEA` stands for Load Effective Address. It's, in this case, a simple addition, as shown above. Typically people and compilers don't really use it anymore because CPUs now ship with a nifty address generation unit (otherwise called AGU), which lets you use all kinds of fancy arithmetics to compute addresses from registers and values. In short, whatever you did with `lea`, you can now embed it inside any other instruction.

Comment: Uh, `lea` instructions are just under 10% of _all_ instructions generated for the code I happen to be working on right now.  It may be true that on x86 you can embed any `lea` operation in a load or store operation (I rather doubt that, honestly), but code is still chock full of pointer arithmetic that doesn't necessarily involve a load or store.

Comment: Yes, it lets you use the power of x86 addressing modes for integer math instead of just for address-generation for loads/stores.  But this is the most backwards and confusing explanation I've ever seen for that fact.  And no, you can't embed that extra math into another instruction.  For example, if I wanted to implement `eax << (edx*2 +1)` I'd want `lea 1(%edx,%edx), %ecx;  shl %cl, %eax`.   I can't write an single `shl` instruction that takes the shift count for EAX from some pre-shift and add on EDX.

Comment: See also [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46597375).  The only time LEA is redundant is if you were using it for actual address-generation before a load or store.  Then yes, sometimes you can just use a complex addressing mode directly for a memory source operand (or even destination).  Although indexed addressing modes can be less efficient on Intel Sandybridge-family: [Micro fusion and addressing modes](//stackoverflow.com/q/26046634)

Answer (score 2):

```
lea ecx,[esp+4]
```

Comment: I'm not the person who downvoted you, but, um, you know the joke about the helicopter pilot and Microsoft technical support?

Comment: I do now. I assumed the question was about deciphering the **at&t syntax**.

Answer (score 1):

`esp` is the stack pointer. 0x4 is the offset. AT&T syntax has the `command source, destination` and the command here is `LEA` which is "Load Effective Address."

So we're telling the CPU to load the address "stack pointer + 4" into the register "ecx"